# ionic tabs icons dynamic color

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, sass

I want to change the icons color of tabs based on a hex variable changed from the api

I've tried to use [ngStyle] and [ngClass] elements and play with them but nothing seems to help

````
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="{{homeTitle}}" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="{{searchTitle}}" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root"  tabIcon="options" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs *ngIf="showKpi">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="{{homeTitle}}" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="{{kpiTitle}}" tabIcon="stats" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="{{searchTitle}}" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root"  tabIcon="options" ></ion-tab>
```</ion-tabs>

I was able to change the background dynamically
````

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[style.color]="myColor"
```

Or

```
[style.backgroundColor]="myColor"
```

And the value of color from the API:

```
this.myColor = 'valueFromAPI'
```

Comment: i've try this but  that won't work in my case since i need to modify the ::before element of the svg icon to give it this color attribute